# ng-model value undefined in controller for custom bootstrap dropdown submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML code

```
<div ng-controller="formController">
<form>
<div class=btn-group>
    <div class="dropdown top-buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="menu-item" ng-model="model.shiftID">Shift</span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a role="menuitem" href="#">E</a></li>
            <li><a role="menuitem" href="#">L</a></li>
            <li><a role="menuitem" href="#">N</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success select-submit" ng-click="getCall()">GO!</button>
</form> 
</div>
```

The angular JS Controller Code

```
.controller("formController", function ($scope)
 {
    // when initialized only the initial value is displayed
    // in the alert. But the passed value through 
    // ng-model directive is still undefined
    $scope.model = {shiftID: "init"};
    $scope.getCall = function () {

         alert($scope.model.shiftID)
    }
    .....
 }
```

I have gone through few other solutions, but not yet able to solve it.

Comment: is your alert giving undefined ?

Comment: yes, @mritunjay, it is giving undefined message

Comment: something going wrong there, because I copied the same and it's working fine for me.

Comment: are u getting alert as init only, coz I am trying to pass it from bootstrap dropdown menu. When I select other menu items, the selected item should also be displayed. But it is not happening. Shall I provide you the whole code ??

Comment: I got init only, i am trying to do that in plunker.

Comment: ok Mritunjay, waiting for it .. M also trying

Comment: I'm not sure, this is the thing you want but i have created this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OzyskzctJxiUuPFaC5q?p=preview) for you.

Comment: have a look on this and let me know.

Comment: the dropdown is not poping up

Comment: fixed @Mritunjay plunker so the dropdown will pop up http://plnkr.co/edit/FhFiKVHvtC7TOLMJWhRy?p=preview

Comment: did you get your solution ? if so tell me what was your problem.

Comment: the dropdown can be fixed including this code

Comment: the dropdown can be fixed including this code  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
   $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.menu-item').html(selText);
   });
});
</script>    ..... Still the DropDown VALUES are not coming as alert